# How to store array of Dates in Database usingJava?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
String[] startD = request.getParameterValues("startD");//Multiples of Dates 


    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    for(int i=0;i<startD.length;i++)
    {
        try {
            Date date = sdf.parse(startD[i]);
            sdate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("SDate "+sdate);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<startD.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Week Dates "+startD[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Is there an actual question here?

Comment: yes how to use String of array to array of dates store in single column name in database

Comment: Are you getting some exception or this code is working? What is the output? If it's working code and you want to create array of dates then use Date[] dates and add sdate to it.

Comment: It's working but output is wrong then how to use Date[] did you give some example please

Comment: Working with dates is aways a pain, but there is is simple path to follow. Store date related data in unix epoch timestamp, which is milliseconds from 1st Jan 1970. Both end conversions are required for this and utility reusable code can help you with conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Date type you should have problems with conversion and locale.
I prefer to convert input date in Instant and then save the Instant value in a 'NUMBER' field of my Oracle Table.

This is an example to convert string Date in Instant:

```
String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
Instant instantdAte = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).parse(avvenimentoSportType.getDtaAvv()).toInstant()
```

I share the [Instant documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).